# htaccess adds unwanted characters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, trailing-slash

I've a htaccess file that looks like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /website/

# add slashes after link/folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/website/$1/ [L,R=301]

# shorten URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&beta=$2&gamma=$3&delta=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&beta=$2&gamma=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&beta=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

It all works fine, until it has to add a slash to a link that has a matching folder on the root directory.

Example: If I write down **www.example.com/live** and there is no folder named "live" in www.example.com/, the script is going to add a slash. However, since there is a folder named "live", the script is once again going to add the slash, but it will also add this ?page=live so the URL will look like this **www.example.com/live/?page=live**

My question is why ?page=something&beta=something&gamma=...etc. is added to the back and how should I make it stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

should fix that.

**edit:** to do what DirectorySlash normally does use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Yep, this did work. Though now it is not adding slash to non-slashed URLs, but still a good solution. Thanks!